# How to create a GMSPlace

Tags: swift, google-maps, google-maps-sdk-ios

I'm using the [Google Maps iOS SDK](https://developers.google.com/maps/documentation/ios-sdk/) and would like to store recent places (`GMSPlace` objects) that users search for. I'm running into a problem retrieving those places, as it doesn't seem like `GMSPlace`s can be instantiated directly.

Is it possible to instantiate a [GMSPlace](https://developers.google.com/maps/documentation/ios-sdk/reference/interface_g_m_s_place) object?

Thanks!

Comment: Wish someone would answer this...  Did you ever figure it out?

Comment: @JohnFarkerson I did not. I don't believe it's possible, though.

Comment: I have added the answer below. Check it out if it works for you and dont forget to upvote. Thanks :D

Answer (score 2):

## CREATE INSTANCE OF GMS PLACE

Yes you can instantiate a GMS Place Object. The day i looked up on the internet , i ran into your question hoping to find an answer but i didn't find any.

So, i came up with my own solution.Here's how you can create an instance of GMSPlace.

So, my requirement was to store 3 GMS Places in 3 different GMSPlace variables. Here's what i did :

```
var currentLocation: GMSPlace?
var selectedFromDestination: GMSPlace?
var selectedToDestination: GMSPlace?
```

Now, currentLocation will store user's current location , selectedFromDestination will store a starting Address Point , whereas selectedToDestination will store a destination Address Point.

Note: Notice that they are all optionals. This is the only i got it to work, since i am still a Noob to Swift.

```
 //MARK:- FUNCTION FOR GETTING CURRENT LOCATION
 func getCurrentPlace() {

    placesClient.currentPlace(callback: { (placeLikelihoodList, error) -> Void in
        if let error = error {
            print("Pick Place error: \(error.localizedDescription)")
            return
        }

        if let placeLikelihoodList = placeLikelihoodList {
            let place = placeLikelihoodList.likelihoods.first?.place
            if let place = place {
                self.nameLabel.text = place.name + "\(place.coordinate.latitude) , \(place.coordinate.longitude)"
                self.addressLabel.text = place.formattedAddress?.components(separatedBy: ", ")
                    .joined(separator: "\n")

                    //assigning returned GMSPlace place object to currentlocation
                    self.currentLocation = place              

            }
        }
    })
}
```

Now, in my `viewDidLoad()` method i called this function `getCurrentPlace()` which will then fetch the user's current location and store in the `currentLocation` variable.

Now, you can access this variable anywhere in your ViewController, and access its properties such as

```
 currentLocation?.formattedAddress
 currentLocation?.coordinate.latitude
 currentLocation?.coordinate.longitude
```

and so on.

Now, you if you want to store what the user selects as a pickup and destination address for example, read on below :-)

Ohkay, so now you have two textfield on which you need to open up the GSMAutoCompleteViewController(P.S - there are other methods but i preferred to use this as it was easy to implement.)

So you will need a textField Delegate method which will differentiate the two textField based on my `strTextFieldType` variable and will present the ViewController.

```
//MARK:- TEXTFIELD DELEGATE
func textFieldShouldBeginEditing(_ textField: UITextField) -> Bool {
    if textField == txtFromDestination
    {
        strTxtFieldType = "FromDestination"

    }
    else if textField == txtToDestination
    {
        strTxtFieldType = "ToDestination"

    }

    let acController = GMSAutocompleteViewController()
    acController.delegate = self
    self.present(acController, animated: true, completion: nil)

    return false
}
```

I have set the return to false as i don't want the textFields to be editable.

Below is the code for the extension which you need to implement for your ViewController

```
extension YOUR_VIEWCONTROLLER_NAME: GMSAutocompleteViewControllerDelegate {

func viewController(_ viewController: GMSAutocompleteViewController, didAutocompleteWith place: GMSPlace) {


    print("Place name: \(place.name)")
    print("Place address: \(place.formattedAddress ?? "null")")

    if strTxtFieldType == "FromDestination"
    {
        self.txtFromDestination.text = place.formattedAddress
        self.selectedFromDestination = place

    }
    else
    {
        self.txtToDestination.text = place.formattedAddress
        self.selectedToDestination = place
    }

    print("Place attributions: \(String(describing: place.attributions))")

    self.dismiss(animated: true, completion: nil)

}

 func viewController(_ viewController: GMSAutocompleteViewController, didFailAutocompleteWithError error: Error) {
    // TODO: handle the error.
    //        print("Error: \(error.description)")
    self.dismiss(animated: true, completion: nil)
}

// User canceled the operation.
func wasCancelled(_ viewController: GMSAutocompleteViewController) {
    print("Autocomplete was cancelled.")
    self.dismiss(animated: true, completion: nil)
}
}
```

There , you are now done. You can access the values stored in selectedFromDestination and selectedToDestination anywhere just like the currentLocation GMSPlace object.

Hope this was helpful; :-D ! Lemme know if it works for you.

Answer (score 1):

No, you can't instantiate a `GMSPlace` object.

Comment: Yes you can, check out my answer below ;-)